# WCF Client Can't connect to Host in same application instance

Tags: c#, wcf, named-pipes

I have a WPF GUI that has two buttons. 
Button 1 creates a new WCF Host that listens for requests via Named Pipes. 
Button 2 uses a Client Proxy DLL to query the Host via Named Pipes.

Clicking button 2, the Client portion is unable to connect.

If however, I run a second instance of the client and click Button 2. It can connect?

The WCF host is running fine, once the server is started. I can also query it with the WCFTestClient ... so the problem only exists within the same instance.

The excpetion thrown is.

---

### This request operation sent to net.pipe://localhost/SvcName did not receive a reply within the configured timeout (00:01:00).  The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.  This may be because the service is still processing the operation or because the service was unable to send a reply message.  Please consider increasing the operation timeout (by casting the channel/proxy to IContextChannel and setting the OperationTimeout property) and ensure that the service is able to connect to the client.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Warrick

Comment: I think this is a threading issue. Can you post your configuration please. Either this can't be done or there's a problem with your configuration. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you mark the class that implements your service with this:

```
 [ServiceBehavior(UseSynchronizationContext = false)]
```

and try again.